# When i use is.na in R, vector is returning NA instead of FALSE

Tags: r, if-statement, na

I want to create a new variable using ifelse and is.na.
But the problem is that this ifelse is only returning 1 and NA.
The problems seems to be in my first ifelse, since I run inside ifelse one by one, and only the first is returning NA. I can't understand why, because the code of the 3 ifelse seems to be similar. Does anyone know?

```
eassociacao<-ifelse((!is.na(dados$CENTRAL)|dados$CENTRAL!=" ") & 
                    (!is.na(dados$SISTEMA)|dados$SISTEMA!=" "),1,
                    ifelse((!is.na(dados$CENTRAL)|dados$CENTRAL!=" ") & 
                           (is.na(dados$SISTEMA)|dados$SISTEMA==" "),2,3))
```

Comment: I think you want to replace 3 first `|` by `&`

Comment: Try this: `eassociacao<-ifelse((!is.na(dados$CENTRAL) != " ") & (!is.na(dados$SISTEMA) != " "), 1,
             ifelse(!is.na(dados$CENTRAL) != " ") & (!is.na(dados$SISTEMA) == " "), 2, 3)`. If it doesn't work, show a reproducible example.

Comment: @cimentadaj that's worse - you are now testing whether the result of `!is.na()` is `!=` to `" "`. Meaningless.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I misunderstood, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3, very good reasons to not use nested ifelse:

1. They are unintuitive and often lead to mistakes.
2. They are hard to understand when you, a year later, have to come back to them.
3. They do not perform as well as clearer alternatives.

Here's an example:

```
eassociacao <- rep(NA_integer_, nrow(dados) # initialize
c1 <- !is.na(dados$CENTRAL) & dados$CENTRAL!=" " # condition 1
c2 <- (!is.na(dados$SISTEMA) & dados$SISTEMA!=" ") # condition 2
c3 <- (is.na(dados$SISTEMA) & dados$SISTEMA==" ") # condition 3

eassociacao[c1 & c2] <- 1 # Push 1 where c1 and c2 are TRUE
eassociacao[c1 & c3] <- 2 # Push 2 where c1 and c3 are TRUE
eassociacao[c1 & !c3] <- 3 # Push 3 where c1 and not c3 are TRUE
```

You may have to split up the conditions to get what you actually want. But TRUST me, when I say this approach will save you time, $, and frsutration in the future.

Comment: I tried doing like you said, but the problem is in the conditions. Somehow it is appearing NA, instead of FALSE.

Comment: c1 <- !is.na(dados$CENTRAL) | dados$CENTRAL!=" "
c2 <- is.na(dados$CENTRAL) | dados$CENTRAL==" "
c3 <- !is.na(dados$SISTEMA) | dados$SISTEMA!=" "
c4 <- is.na(dados$SISTEMA) | dados$SISTEMA==" "

Comment: I am havin problem with the or function

Comment: I don't understand your logic so well, this answer is more guidance rather than an explicit answer to your problem. You will have to provide a reproducible sample of your data to continue.